# Scale Interface to VB Application

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I have a few different scales that I'm building a VB app for.  Is there a universal serial port language that is common among weight scales that I can use to import real-time weight into VB?

Comment: What sort of weight scales? I mean, for all we know you could be weighing a teaspoon of sugar, or a car! No offence :) Give us some brand names and model makes of the scales, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a standard protocol, formulated by the Scale Manufacturer Association.  The spec download [is here](http://www.scalemanufacturers.org/PDF/ScaleCommProtocol5199M1.pdf).  Whether your actual scales follow that standard is an open question, check the small print in the datasheet or programming manual for them.  It is rarely a real problem, these protocols are easy with simple command/response strings.

Comment: the above link is dead this is the right link http://www.scalemanufacturers.org/PDF/ScaleCommProtocol5199M1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found reading the ZBI 2/ ZPL Manuals of Zebra. very usefull!!!!

```
1 rem ********************************************************
05 for i = 1 to 9 step 1
10 close #i
20 next i
30 open # 2 : name "SER"
40 open # 1 : name "ZPL"
1 rem ********************************************************
1 rem main program; send serial port a 'W' in order to get a weight
1 rem ********************************************************
50 do
60 do
70 sleep 1 ! sleep so scale is not bombarded with incoming
1 rem data
80 print # 2 : "W" ; ! semicolon ends sent W without a CRLF
1 rem ********************************************************
1 rem get response from scale; note that input requires a CRLF to be
1 rem entered
1 rem ********************************************************
90 input # 2 : a$
100 if a$ = "EXIT" then! back door exit - if EXIT is received, ZBI ends
110 close # 2
120 print #1: "^XZ"
130 close #1
140 end
150 end if
1 rem ********************************************************
1 rem loop until valid weight is received, then print on label
1 rem ********************************************************
160 loop while pos ( a$ , "000.00" ) = 1 or pos ( a$ , "?" ) = 1
170 print # 1 : "~SD25^XA^FS";
180 print # 1 : "^LH0,0^FS";
190 print # 1 : "^FO56,47^A0N,69,58^FDThis weighs^FS";
1 rem ********************************************************
1 rem print weight on label; & character concatenates strings
1 rem ********************************************************
200 print # 1 : "^FO56,150^A0N,69,58^FD" & A$ & " lbs^FS";
210 print # 1 : "^PQ1,0,0,N";
220 print # 1 : "^XZ"
1 rem ********************************************************
1 rem loop until weight is off scale, then repeat for next item
1 rem weighed
1 rem ********************************************************
230 do
240 print # 2 : "W" ;
250 input # 2 : A$
260 loop until pos(A$ , "000.00") = 1 or pos(A$ , "?") = 1
270 loop
```